# If results are not >= "Number" then show blank

Tags: crystal-reports-2008

New to building Crystal Reports and SQL.

I'm trying to write a script to where if results is >= 12.1 then show  result else show no results.

Same goes for the <=9.9.

Here is what I have so far:

```
if {Test.Name} = "xyz" and {TestResults.numresult}>= 12.1 then {TestResults.numresult} else "";
```

Below is an image showing the same results across the board. I just want the results to show when its <=9.9 or >=12.1.
Hope this make sense.

[image: Result Outcome]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your statement returns a number from one branch and a string from the other. It must return the same data type.

One option is to use a True/False expression in a Suppress expression.

Another option is to return a zero in the other branch and use number formatting to suppress if zero (it's a built-in option for numbers).

Another option is to modify your expression so it returns a string from both branches. For example:

```
if {Test.Name} = "xyz" and {TestResults.numresult}>= 12.1 then ToText({TestResults.numresult}, 1, ",") else "";
```

The 1 argument requests 1 decimal point. The "," argument requests a comma as thousands separator. You can adjust those to match your number formatting requirements.

Comment: The expression you given me, I've tried using it in the Formula Fields of where "xyz" is. I received an error message from my web page when trying to pull that report. 

When running the expression in the "Running Total Fields" of where the "RT XYZ" is, the report DOES NOT give me an error message but the results show blank. 

What am I doing wrong? 

Also, Thank you for your time on answering this question. Much appreciated.